# Can you set a PrivateBinPath for a process?

Tags: c#

I have some code that creates an AppDomain. It sets the PrivateBinPath to tell it where to load some of the referenced assemblies.

For various technical reasons, I now need to run this code in a separate Process instead. However, I can't find an equivalent to PrivateBinPath for the Process type. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It's extraordinarily rare to have to run a *separate process*.  What limit do you believe you ran into?

Comment: @erik-philips for larger systems in particular, it's not at all unusual to run code in separate processes

Comment: @cocowalla Generally moving from using AppDomains to using Separate processes is sometimes done because of a poor understanding of the Framework.  Before going down that road, it's best to ask what difficulties there were that made that decision to begin with.

Comment: The primary executable is 32 bit. I need to run this extra code as a 64 bit process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but the `probing` [configuration element] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element) `privatePath` attribute sounds like what you need:

> Specifies subdirectories of the application's base directory that might contain assemblies. Delimit each subdirectory with a semicolon

You'd put this in the XML application config file, `Myapp.exe.config`, which needs to be in the executable's folder (it might not already exist, as these config files are used less and less these days)